# Views changefilter/argument when no results occur

Tags: views, search

i am using a date range filter which will list news for this week(Sunday to Saturday of current week). Am getting the results correctly.
Now am want to show the news for next week if there is no news for current week

Comment: I dont think if its possible with views itself. You need to write some custom code for it. May be `hook_views_pre_render` would help you.

Comment: Check this :

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/75764/conditionally-run-a-view-if-another-view-has-no-results